# JavaScript: Redirect to a URL with query string in HiddenField

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html-table, hidden-field

I'm using asp.net. I have a table in a repeater. I keep the ID's of the items in the repeater in an hiddenfield in the last column of the table with an edit hyperlink, and when it's clicked the user is redirected to the edit page of the item, which has a url like `/ItemEdit.aspx?ItemID=236`

Now, my problem is, instead of using an edit button, I want the user to be redirected to the edit page when he/she clicks on anywhere on the row. I've added an onclick event to the `<tr>` tag, and it works when I put static links. However as my hiddenfield is in a `<td>` tag, I cannot reach the value of the ID of the item. My code is something like:

```
 <tr onclick="var itemID=document.getElementById('hdnItemID').value; location.href='ItemEdit.aspx?ItemID='+itemID;">
    <td>Some stuff about the item</td>
    <td>Some other stuff about the item </td>
    <td><asp:HiddenField ID="hdnItemID" runat="server" Value='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemID")%>' /></td>
</tr>
```

And as expected, browser has no idea what `hdnItemID` is. How to solve this problem? Where to add the hiddenfield and how to get the value of it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question as I copied `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemID")%>` in javascript code directly, that is, I switched my `<tr>` tag into:

```
<tr onclick="location.href='ItemEdit.aspx?ItemID='+<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ItemID")%>">
```

And it works.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the ASP language. But in your case you will get many hidden fieds with the same id **hdnItemID**. And an ID must be unique on a web page.